# SDL Window can't be restored after minimising

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, window, sdl

The problem occurs when

```
SDL_RestoreWindow(gameWindow);
```

is called on a minimised window. The window does not re-appear.

I've made a little dummy program simulating the sort of SDL calls that my main program is calling, and the problem reproduces. Here is the code:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argn, char **argv)
{
    // The windows    
    SDL_Window *gameWindow;           

    // Initialise
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);             

    // Create window
    gameWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Game Window",                 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           
        640,                               
        480,                               
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  
    );

    // Minimise/ hide or whatever?
    SDL_MinimizeWindow(gameWindow);

    // Wait
    SDL_Delay(1000);

    // Attempt to bring back the window
    SDL_RestoreWindow(gameWindow);

    // program would run here
    SDL_Delay(1000);

    // quit out
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gameWindow);

    // Clean up
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas as to why this gameWindow is not re-appearing?
Is SDL_Restore not designed to restore a minimised window?

Also FYI This is running on Ubuntu 13.10 and compiling with gcc 4.8.1 and Gnome metacity 2.34.13

Comment: What values do the functions return?

Comment: SDL_RestoreWindow and the others return void as per https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RestoreWindow

Comment: Can't seem to repro this (different env though). In your test case, do you see a window pop-up before you minimize? Does SDL_CreateWindow return successfully? Have you tried without OpenGL (try the flag SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)?

Comment: Yeah I see the window pup-up, then minimise, but never return. Also SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN doesn't seem to make a difference here either.
I'll check this out on a different env though and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

Make sure you call one of the functions that let SDL process events: `SDL_PollEvent()` or `SDL_WaitEvent()` or `SDL_PumpEvents()`.

#### Longer answer

It is possible that the reason why the window can't be restored is because it does not have `SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED` flag assigned to it.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/629e9f820a3ab80e7671ab3133a448f56252f1da/src/video/SDL_video.c#L2417-L2429) of the `SDL_RestoreWindow()` function:

```c
void
SDL_RestoreWindow(SDL_Window * window)
{
    CHECK_WINDOW_MAGIC(window,);

    if (!(window->flags & (SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED | SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED))) {
        return;
    }

    if (_this->RestoreWindow) {
        _this->RestoreWindow(_this, window);
    }
}
```

If neither `SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED` nor `SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED` are set, the `_this->RestoreWindow()` will not be called (and the window will not be restored).

Normally when a window is being minimized the `SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED` flag is set by SDL in `SDL_SendWindowEvent()` [function](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/c59d4dcd38c382a1e9b69b053756f1139a861574/src/events/SDL_windowevents.c#L126-L133):

```c
    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MINIMIZED:
        if (window->flags & SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED) {
            return 0;
        }
        window->flags &= ~SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED;
        window->flags |= SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED;
        SDL_OnWindowMinimized(window);
        break;
```

This will happen when SDL processes events queue. Processing of the events should be triggered by your application as described in the [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryEvents):

> Internally, SDL stores all the events waiting to be handled in an
> event queue. Using functions like SDL_PollEvent(), SDL_PeepEvents()
> and SDL_WaitEvent() you can observe and handle waiting input events.

If you do not want to receive and handle input events, you can call `SDL_PumpEvents()` [function](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents) to let SDL process the events:

> This function updates the event queue and internal input device state.

> Often the need for calls to SDL_PumpEvents() is hidden from the user since SDL_PollEvent() and SDL_WaitEvent() implicitly call SDL_PumpEvents(). However, if you are not polling or waiting for events (e.g. you are filtering them), then you must call SDL_PumpEvents() to force an event queue update.